# Android: Portrait image not on the entire screen

Tags: android, image

The effect I want to create is on picture 1, but I have picture 2.

[image]

**When I lauch the app I want my image to be full height and width, just like picture one.** 
I tried chaning the images width and height but it still won't fit. I tried using:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

and

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

But that just streches the image and still is not full height (picture 3):

[image]

So I am asking do I need to change the images with-height or what to make that picture full width and height when I lauch the app. The *Temperatura* card is suppose to be on the bottom of the picture so I get the effect like *Monday* on picture 1. The *testServer* text is when the user starts scrolling down.

I put the image in drawable folders in different dimensions.
In this xxxhdpi (for my LG G3), the resolution is 1280x1920.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.41"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/blood"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                />

            <!--Temperatura card-->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                android:layout_margin="11dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:text="Temperatura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/naslovTemp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalnaCrtaDva"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/white" />

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
                        android:weightSum="1"
                        android:id="@+id/unutrasnjaKartica">

                        <!--Prva unutrasnja kartica - Najnovije vreme - 1 - 22:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="22:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/prviSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="10°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/prviPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Druga unutrasnja kartica - 2 -  18:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="18:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/drugiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="11°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/drugiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Treca unutrasnja kartica - 3 - 14:00  -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="14:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/treciSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="15°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/treciPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Cetvrta unutrasnja kartica - 4 - 12:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="12:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/cetvrtiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="11°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/cetvrtiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Peta unutrasnja kartica - 5 - 09:00  -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="09:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/petiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="8°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/petiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Sesta unutrasnja kartica - Drugi dan - 6 - 22:00  -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="22:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/sestiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="16°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/sestiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Sedma unutrasnja kartica - 7 - 18:00  -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="18:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/sedmiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="17°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/sedmiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Osma unutrasnja kartica - 8 - 14:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="14:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/osmiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="10°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/osmiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Deveta unutrasnja kartica - 9 - 12:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="12:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/devetiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="20°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/devetiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                        <!--Deseta unutrasnja kartica - 10 - 09:00 -->
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                                >

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="09:00"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:id="@+id/desetiSatTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:text="17°C"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:id="@+id/desetiPrikazTemp"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textSize="25sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    />

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>


        <!-- TestServerText -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.ivanp.cardivantestdva.MainActivity"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <TextView
                android:text="testServer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/testServer"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your xml code also

Answer (score 0):

you are using a toolbar/appbar,you need to lose that- delete it from your xml file.
if you have the android:fitsSystemWindows="true" attribute change it to false.

if you can post your xml file i think i can help you more.

Comment: I added my XML, it's long only because of the Temperatura card, look around it :)

Comment: Ok, I see you are not using any unnecessary margins or fitSystemWindow. in that case try changing the Activity theme by using: <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>  in your styles. and add the following attribute to the manifest: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"